# How to use nested selectors with Emotion CSS object styles

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I've been trying to use [this dropdown tutorial](https://moderncss.dev/css-only-accessible-dropdown-navigation-menu/) to create a hoverable dropdown menu with React and Emotion CSS. Here's the part I'm stuck at:

```
.dropdown {
  // ... existing styles

  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    .dropdown__menu {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateX(0) translateX(-50%);
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to show a menu when you hover over a button. This is a cut down version of my app file, showing what I've got so far:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';

const styles = {
  menu: css({
    // ...
    transform: 'rotateX(-90deg) translateX(-50%)',
    transformOrigin: 'top center',
    opacity: '0.3',
    visibility: 'hidden',
    transition: '280ms all ease-out',
  }),
  button: css({
    maxWidth: '50px',
    maxHeight: '50px',
    padding: '7px',

    '&:hover [data-css="dropdown-menu"]': {
      opacity: 1,
      visibility: 'visible',
      transform: 'rotateX(0) translateX(-50%)',
    },
  }),
};

const AccountMenu = () => (
    <div css={styles.container}>
      <button
        aria-expanded='false'
        aria-controls='account-menu'
        css={styles.button}
        type="button"
      >
        Hover over me
      </button>
      <div css={styles.menu} id='account-menu' data-css='dropdown-menu'>
        <span>Dropdown menu details...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
);

export default AccountMenu;
```

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1866#issuecomment-628477225) which links to [this CodeSandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ramanujan-jlhds?file=/src/App.js). I want to do this using object styles instead, but I can't get the data[] selector working. I also tried assigning a `className` to the menu `div` and accessing it like `'#account-menu': {` but that also didn't work.

My 2 questions are:

1. How do I get the `&:hover, &:focus-within {` part working? I get errors when trying to use multiple selectors.
2. How do I reference the menu `div` inside the button CSS object to make it visible on hover?

Comment: This answer helped me get pseudo-classes working with CSS objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67974518/463645